# Conditional INSERT mysql query error

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `items` (`item_did_sell`, `sold_for`, `bought_by_paddle`) 
                SELECT ('1','{$sold_for}','{$paddle_number}') 
                FROM `items` WHERE index_number={$index_number}") or die('error!!!' . mysql_error());
```

Im getting this error:

```
error!!!Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

And I don't understand why.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here it is with the php vars replaced with test values:

```
 mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `items` (`item_did_sell`, `sold_for`, `bought_by_paddle`) 
                SELECT ('1','2500','111') 
                FROM `items` WHERE index_number=555") or die('error!!!' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why the `{ ... }` around your values?

Comment: You might print out that SQL statement with the values of your variables. If that doesn't already show your problem directly, at least it'll make it easier for us here to find anything.

Comment: perhaps this is new in later version of PHP, but I have never wrapped them in braces. Just place the variable name into the query string.

Comment: you probably wanted to use ${sold_for} syntax, which is redundant here - its needed when your var has some special character inside, ie. ${array['key']}. underscore works fine without braces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **[`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html)** syntax has no parenthesis `( )` around the list.

Remove them from the `SELECT` list:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `items` (`item_did_sell`, `sold_for`, `bought_by_paddle`) 
                SELECT '1','{$sold_for}','{$paddle_number}' 
                FROM `items` WHERE index_number={$index_number}") 
  or die('error!!!' . mysql_error());
```

---

If, on the other hand (as I understand from the comments), you want to update the existing row that has `index_number={$index_number}`, use **[`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)**:

```
mysql_query ("UPDATE `items`  
              SET `item_did_sell` = '1', 
                  `sold_for` = '{$sold_for}',
                  `bought_by_paddle` {$paddle_number}
              WHERE index_number={$index_number}") 
  or die('error!!!' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! But can you explain to me why you wouldn't use the parenthesis? I like to know why I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you sue you want to `INSERT` and not `UPDATE` by the way?

Comment: When the "item" is inserted into the table, 'item_did_sell', 'sold_for', and 'bought_by_paddle' are all set to NULL by default. It is at this query's run-time that that information is added to the table. Would it be better to use UPDATE in this case? Im a junior in high school just getting into mysql and php so this is all a learning experience.

Comment: This statement as it is, will (try to) add a new row in the table, it will not chnage (update) existing row with `index_number={$index_number}`. If you want to do that, use [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html)